# SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column does not exist Позиция: 8

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, entity

Столкнулся с ошибкой маппинга колонок таблицы с Entity,
если поля в таблице Postgres написаны с большой буквы.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accdivtype", schema = "public")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class AccDivType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "AccDivTypeID")
    private long accDivTypeID;
```

ERROR: column accdivtype0_.acc_div_typeid does not exist

фото самой таблицы внутри схемы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть ли решение как это исправить, без переименования колонок?

Comment: Очень странно, ругается на колонку `acc_div_typeid` с нижним подчеркиванием, хотя в БД и в аннотации указано `AccDivTypeID`. В сущности точно нет еще одной колонки с `@Column(name = "acc_div_typeid")` или отдельного native запроса? Другие поля преобразуются из camelCase в UnderScoreCase? Добавьте в вопрос больше данных из ошибки.

Comment: нет другого поля. сущность одна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать двойные кавычки в именах полей, выдержка из [справки](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/sql-syntax-lexical):
Идентификатор, заключённый в кавычки, становится зависимым от регистра, **тогда как идентификаторы без кавычек всегда переводятся в нижний регистр**. Например, идентификаторы FOO, foo и "foo" считаются одинаковыми в PostgreSQL, но "Foo" и "FOO" отличны друг от друга и от предыдущих трёх. (Приведение имён без кавычек к нижнему регистру, как это делает PostgreSQL, несовместимо со стандартом SQL, который говорит о том, что имена должны приводиться к верхнему регистру. То есть, согласно стандарту foo должно быть эквивалентно "FOO", а не "foo". Поэтому при создании переносимых приложений рекомендуется либо всегда заключать определённое имя в кавычки, либо не заключать никогда.)

Comment: я пробовал прописать @Column(name = "\"AccDivTypeID\"") но почему то проблема осталась, именно для этого поля. для остальных решение сработало.

Comment: Попробуете поле не набить руками а скопировать например через pgAdmin4, при этом убедитесь что нет краевых пробелов, если будет работать - ищите партизанский символ на кириллице, чудес не бывает.

Comment: да я копировал через поле в окне datasourse  в idee, если бы был символ кириллицы то она б подчеркнула) попробую подключиться через shh. к базе посмотреть

Comment: Я когда мапинг делаю или большие POCO классы использую функцию, может пригодится.
https://dbfiddle.uk/_FPMWWkz

Comment: я кажется понял, видимо дело в hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy.
с такой отработало.
 jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy

Comment: По всей вероятности все это нацелено на создание схемы средствами используемой вами библиотеки доступа, тогда были бы выполнены все требования по именованию полей внутри схемы, в том числе замена верхнего регистра на подчеркивание скрывает от конечного пользователя проблему с преобразованием в нижний регистр. Действительно если более пристально посмотреть на ответ сервера то видно что имя поля изменено в соответствии с предоставленными вами сведениями.